# Function.prototype.call unexpected behavior when assigned to a variable

Tags: javascript

The following code calls `console.log` prints "hello":

```
console.log.call(console, "hello")
```

However, the code below throws TypeError:

```
x = console.log.call
x(console, "hello")
```

throws:

```
Uncaught TypeError: x is not a function
    at <anonymous>:1:1
```

Can anyone explain this weird scenario?

(Of course it's the same for both `call` and `apply`)

Comment: I did ask my self similair question over and over , unfortunatly i never was able to find the answer

Comment: `x is not a function` is a confusing and misleading error message in Chrome (because x actually _is_ a function). Firefox puts it much better: "TypeError: Function.prototype.call called on incompatible undefined".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`.call` gets the function to call from its `this` parameter.

You're calling it via `x` with no `this` parameter, so it has no function to call (or rather, it tries to call `window`) and gives an error.

You need to bind your `x` variable to the `log` function:

```
x = console.log.call.bind(console.log);
```

**Bonus**: `.call` comes from `Function.prototype`, and is the same no matter how you access it.  Therefore, `Function.call.bind(console.log)` also works (because `Function` is a function and therefore has `.call`).  As does `Date.call`.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks, what confused me was the error message.

Answer (score 3):

Note: I will use `apply` instead of `call` in my answer just because the wording/reading is a bit less confusing but the same answer stands for `call`.

You can imagine `apply` looking something like this:

```
Function.prototype.apply = function apply(context, rest) {
  // `this` in here is the function object on which we call `apply` as a method
  // we then invoke whatever is bound to `this` (it should be the function that was "applied")
  // and change its context and pass the rest of the arguments
  // Note: I'm using `call` since we don't have access to native function  code that can call a function with an overwritten context
  this.call(context, ...rest)
}
```

When you call the `apply` function (or any function for that matter) as a method on a function object ([functions are first-class objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions)), `this` within it gets bound to the function (object) on which you called `apply` (this is one of the [rules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on how context is bound in JS when a function is called as a method of an object)

```js
Function.prototype.apply = function apply(context, rest) {
  this.call(context, ...rest)
  // `this` is the function that `call` invokes
  // in the example bellow, `this` is `console.log`
  // so this function will do `console.log.call(console, 'example')`
}

console.log.apply(console, ['example'])
// ^^^^^^^^ console.log is the context because we are calling `apply` on it, with the dot (.) notation
```

However, when you store the `apply` function into a variable and invoke it then, then the rule for `this` binding is it to be `undefined` (in strict mode or the global `window` otherwise) and thus there's no function to call under the hood.

```js
Function.prototype.apply = function apply(context, rest) {
  this.call(context, ...rest)
  // using the example bellow
  // `this` is `undefined` now because `apply` was called like a regular function, not a method
  // which means the code bellow does `undefined.call(console, 'example')`
}


// calling a function as a normal function (not a method via the dot notation), makes `this` be `undefined`
// therefore `apply` doesn't have a function which to call with an overwritten context
let apply = console.log.apply;
apply(console, ['example']) // error, `this.call is not a function`
```

Answer (score 0):

In fact the scenario is normal.
You need to declare `x` as a function who encapsulate your logic like this:

ps: `...args` is the spread operator in javascript (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
x = (...args) => console.log.call(...args)
x(console, "hello")
```